# Remote and Local IP address - determine location

Tags: ip, geolocation

There is way to determine location (on a map) remote IP.

Was wondering how to determine user location if I now local IP?

Comment: What do you mean by local and remote IP?

Comment: Do you mean determining their location from their local network (i.e.  192.168.X.X) address? You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about an IP address in the Private Domain (192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x, 10.x.x.x) then it is impossible to determine as there can be duplicates of these IPs anywhere in the world.

If you are talking about an IP address in the Public Domain, you can google for one of the countless IP location services available, just enter the IP, and it will give you APPROXIMATE information about it's location, sometimes specific information if the IP address is allocated to a business.